# formula for equation with exponent variable?

Tags: exponentiation, nonlinear-system

is there a closed formula for such an equation to find the value of $x$ in

$ax = b^x$

if there isn't , are there any published attempts ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution of $ax = b^x$ is given by $$x=-\frac{W\left(-\frac{\log (b)}{a}\right)}{\log (b)}$$ where $W(z)$ is [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) such that $z=W(z)\,e^{W(z)}$.

It is a very interesting, fascinating, useful function with alot of partical applications.

Search on this site; you would find a lot of QA about it.